# javascript - console.log prints an array with its brackets " [ ]" and not just the content

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code

```js
var family = ["Jullia", "James", "Eva"];
console.log(family);
```

And as you can see, when you run the code, it prints the brackets as well. Why?

(I am new to javascript so i know that this might seem like a stupid question to ask..)

Comment: That's how the used console is designed. Note, that the log result is "live" (not in the StackSnippet console), you can open the tree and inspect all the properties of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply how your console has chosen to represent arrays—by writing each element enclosed in brackets. It helps the programmer know that what has been printed is an array of elements. I would not rely on this "stringified" version, though, if you're trying to print names in a specific way.

To do that, I would suggest learning about `Array.join()` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)), where the examples do exactly as you might want.